# Determine Facebook likes of a page via php?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think Facebook changed something with their API. A few days ago my code stopped working. I used the following code to read the number of likes of a FB page:

```
<?php
$link = "http://graph.facebook.com/pagename";
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$json = json_decode($json);
?>

<div class="fb_likes">
<p><?hp echo $json->{'likes'}; ?>
```

Does anybody know what has changed and how I can read the number of likes now?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Looking forward for an answer to this problem. I think @Torben is talking about getting the number of likes for the facebook page not for a custom url using the FQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve fb like count with function below:

```
function facebook_count($url){
  $fql  = "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count ";
  $fql .= " FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url'";
  $fqlURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=" . urlencode($fql);
  $response = file_get_contents($fqlURL);
  return json_decode($response);
}
$fb = facebook_count('https://www.facebook.com/pages/Coca-Cola/1517438451865061');
echo $fb[0]->like_count;
```

Comment: fql is deprecated and does not work in new apps anymore

Comment: ...also, it´s about getting the likes of a facebook page, not an external website.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say if we only know that it "stopped working", but you do need to use an Access Token for that call now. You also have to specify the fields you want to get. For example:

```
$link = "https://graph.facebook.com/pagename?fields=name,likes&access_token=xxx";
```

Information about the different Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

More information in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: I can confirm that luschn answer is working but the call needs to be made using https. Also the access-token at the end is actually the App_ID|App_Secret.

Comment: thanx for the comment, i changed http to https. the simple app token is explained in the links i posted.

Comment: Apps' secret key should not be used in the URL. To keep the data and app secure, Access token was invented.

Comment: that is wrong, it´s no problem at all to use the secret on the server. and there are many different access tokens, the app token even includes the app secret directly. access tokens were invented for user/page sessions.

Comment: btw, i had to reject your change request, using "pagename" was intentional. you CAN use the pagename in the API call and the starter of this thread did use it too. changing it to pageid would be confusing.